# Shared NSUserDefault between sandboxed OSX app and extension

Tags: xcode, macos, nsuserdefaults, appstore-sandbox, appgroups

**Background**

I'm developing an OSX application with an associated Today Widget extension. I'd like for the main app and the extension to share user preferences, much like is described in [Sharing Data with Your Containing App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6) from Apple. In my case, the main app writes the preferences and the extension reads them.

- OSX 10.11.6
- Xcode 7.3.1
- Swift 2.2

Both the app and the extension are sandboxed. They also are members of the same application group. Relevant entitlements, verified using 
`codesign -d --entitlements`, on both the app and extension:

```
com.apple.security.app-sandbox: true
com.apple.security.application-groups:
  - com.example.Common
```

**Code**

The app and extensions share the same code to initialize and access `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSUserDefaults.init(suiteName: "com.example.Common")
```

**Problem**

The main app creates the preferences in:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.example/Data/Library/Preferences/com.example.Common.plist
```

When the extension is then opened, its `NSUserDefault` instance is empty.

If I move the plist created by the app to:

```
~/Library/Group Containers/com.example.Common/Library/Preferences/com.example.Common.plist
```

The extension's `NSUserDefault` instance is populated with the expected values.

**Note**:
The following doesn't happen when building and running the app from Xcode, only when selecting Product -> Archive, then Export -> Export as a Mac Application. When building/running from Xcode, the main app creates the plist file where the extension expects it as described above.

Answer (score 0):

I do same thing right now — sandbox app + Share Extension + NSUserDefault + application groups, and it's work fine. Maybe Apple fixed few bugs during this time?